# text adjustment without touching the style sheet

Tags: html, css

I have an image and i want to write some text over it. all the files are using the same style sheet but this image in particular needs some adjustment. i have an image and a layer which allows me to write text on top in order for me to add text to it. I need to add a  margin-left but i don't want to touch the style sheet since all the other files are using the same styling. Only this image in particular need to be changed for the writing to be in the center. Is there any way i can accomplish this

Comment: How do you have the image ? As `<img>`  ?

Comment: give the `img` an id the write a style for that id

Comment: How are you interacting or setting up images and text? Your question is a bit vague. Could you please provide the relevant HTML and CSS so we have something to work with?

Comment: inline styling or `<style>` tag?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

well you can inline style. You can control the text you write over your image looks by using if you want `<span>` and inline style.

```
"<span style='font-size:15px;'>" + your text + "</span>";
```